# NullPointerException in SynchronousQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception

I get this error rarely (less than once in 10 000 runs):

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

(I hand copied the error message so there may be typos.)

I have no idea where to start investigating, as the error message does not tell what part of my code causes the error. The program is large (approximately 12 000 lines of code), and it uses threads in many places, so it is not easy to guess what might be the cause. I use ExecutorService to start new threads.

The issue only happens in production. The program is executed once per minute and the error happens usually in a 2 week interval. The error causes server to hang and I must restart it manually and it is very irritating. I have tried to run program in debug environment but have never got this error.

I'm using JRE build `1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-3-b14`.

Do you have any ideas what might be the cause of error and how to prevent it?

Comment: please tell which java version you are using.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I added it to the post.

Comment: This part: "The error causes server to hang and I must restart it manually " suggests that you should perform a ThreadDump to see where your thread is hanging. What applications server are you using? Try using some JProfiler to see what is going on on the server

Comment: did you try to look at the source code, line 461 in  SynchronousQueue.java?